# Computing gradient and hessian in sympy at certain points

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I've been trying to compute gradient and Hessian of a multivariable equation in sympy. The code goes as follows:

```py
s = (x,y,z)
f1 = ((1-x)**2) + 2*(2*y**2-x)**2 + 3*(2*z**2 - y)**2
gradient = lambda f, v: Matrix([f]).jacobian(v).T
H = hessian(f1,[x,y,z])
```

I want to compute gradient and hessian at `(1,2,0)` loaded in `np.array`. `f1` is Dixon-Price function. Any help is highly appreciated. Also, I found that calculating the value of an expression whose value is 0 takes more time than whose value is not 0. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```py
>>> r = dict(zip(s,(1,2,0)))  # or dict(zip(s, np array))
>>> list(gradient(f1, s).subs(r))
[-28, 236, 0]
>>> str(H.subs(r))
Matrix([[6, -32, 0], [-32, 374, 0], [0, 0, -48]])
```

Answer (score 0):

smichr answer is good. If you plan to evaluate your Hessian on many points, then you'd be better converting the Hessian expression to a numerical function using `lambdify`: the evaluation will use Numpy, which is a lot faster.

One approach is the following:

```py
point = np.array([1,2,0])
nH = lambdify([x, y, z], H)
nH(*point)
```

Note that it returns an numpy array.

If you don't like the starred expression, we can modify the Hessian matrix to use indexed objects instead of symbols:

```py
a = IndexedBase("a")
r = {v: a[i] for i, v in enumerate([x, y, z])}
print(r)
# {x: a[0], y: a[1], z: a[2]}
nH = lambdify(a, H.subs(r))
nH(point)
```